# get relevent id for a date from the database

Tags: java, hibernate

i tried to get the relevent id for the selected date in hibernate.but it returns 0 size list.but the date is exist in the data base.but i cant get the id for that date

```
   transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            Query query = session.createQuery(" FROM RoomRate WHERE currdate='" + date + "'");
            List<RoomRate> list = (List<RoomRate>) query.list();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at these examples

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-examples/

The key point being that the date needs to be formatted as in

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

and then you can query using

```
" where date >= '" + sdf.format(startDate) + "'"
```

BTW - why do you have a transaction  and a commit on a select?

Comment: my asking question permission is banned..please help me